# IProblem with backing up mysql database

Tags: mysql, backup

I have problem when backing up mysql database. When I use the following command, it works fine

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin mysqldump.exe 
    --user=dinesh 
    --password=accounting 
    --host=dinesh 
    -C 
    --routines 
    --default-character-set=utf8 
    --Opt inventory 
    > C:\\R14122009_12469.Sql
```

But when I pass Path like

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\Wild\Desktop\f report\New Folder\R14122009_12469.Sql"
```

It shows an error `table not found`

Is there any way where I can save the backup at any place at runtime selection?

Comment: Can you show your exact command line call?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `--result-file=` parameter to `mysqldump`? It is anyway recommended on Windows to avoid problems with newlines.